# Constructor invocation without parentheses

Tags: javascript, constructor, new-operator

Is there any difference between

```
var obj1 = new Constructor;
```

and

```
var obj2 = new Constructor();
```

given that `Constructor` is a constructor function?

Comment: If you don't need arguments, `new Constructor;` will save 2 bytes.

Comment: @Mageek no it's not:  that's a C++ question; this is Javascript.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new):

> [...] "new foo" is equivalent to "new foo()", i.e. if no argument list is
>   specified, "foo" is called without arguments.